# Question about the formulation of Bayes' rule

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics

Can someone explain how we get from this:

$p(θ|y)=\frac{p(y,θ)}{p(y)}$

to this:

$p(θ|y)∝p(y,θ)$

I have read [A question about notation of Bayes' Theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36029/a-question-about-notation-of-bayes-theorem) and [What is meant by this formulation of Bayes' Rule?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124630/what-is-meant-by-this-formulation-of-bayes-rule?rq=1), which are both useful, but do not elaborate on this particular step.

Comment: Observe that $p(y)$ is independent of $\theta$; as you change $\theta$, $p(y)$ remains the same.  Thus, it is a *constant*.  If you have $p(\theta|y) = c*p(y,\theta)$, then $p(\theta|y) \propto p(y,\theta)$.

Comment: The independency of $p(y)$ from $\theta$ is creating me conceptual problems here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/532377/noob-question-about-bayes-rule-denominator-estimation/532390?noredirect=1#comment978400_532390

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bayes' (1763) inversion: 
$$\underbrace{p(θ|y)}_{\substack{\text{conditional on $y$,}\\ \text{ meaning $y$ is fixed}}}=\frac{\overbrace{p(y,θ)}^{\substack{\text{function of $\theta$ only}\\ \text{since $y$ is fixed}}}}{\underbrace{p(y)}_\text{constant}}=\frac{\overbrace{p(y|θ)p(θ)}^\text{same thing...}}{\underbrace{p(y)}_\text{constant}}\propto p(y|θ)p(θ)$$
where the proportionality is between two functions of $\theta$ that differ by a multipliactive constant

Answer (score 1):

The symbol in the 2nd formula means "proportional to" which means that the left side is equal to the right side times a constant (and the constant does not need to be known).  The denominator in the top equation is a constant (given the data), so the 2 are equivalent by definition, the 2nd just leaves out the constant denominator.