# Noob question about bayes rule denominator estimation

Tags: probability, bayesian, marginal-distribution

A known problem of Bayes rule is the intractability of the estimation of $p(D)$ given a multiparametric problem, since $p(D)$ is found by marginalizing the joint probability $p(D, \theta_{1..n})$ over the whole n-dimensions $\theta$ space.

But I was wondering, since $p(D)$, in theory, does not depend on the actual parameterization of the model (otherwise it would be conditional on $\theta$ and not marginal), wouldn't be sufficient to estimate in a way that doesn't use $\theta$ at all?
I wouldn't know how to do it with no parameters at all, but the first thing that comes to my mind would be to use a simplified model with just one parameter to integrate over and then use the $p(D)$ estimated this way as a denominator of the joint density of the complex model.

What am I missing? If one can compute $p(D)$ analytically (or numerically but fast) from a simpler model, couldn't she plug it into a complex model to avoid using MCMC to estimate the normalized posterior?

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one possible model for the joint distribution. Let's index two of them by $A$ and $B$:
\begin{equation}
p(D,\theta|A) \quad\text{versus} \quad p(D,\theta|B) . 
\end{equation}
It follows that there are two different marginal likelihoods for the data, one for each model:
\begin{equation}
p(D|A) = \int p(D,\theta|A)\,d\theta 
\quad\text{versus}\quad
p(D|B) = \int p(D,\theta|B)\,d\theta. 
\end{equation}

Is one of the models correct? Which one is better?

To strip things down to the bare essentials, consider two models for $D$, neither of which has any parameters:
\begin{equation}
p(D|A) = \textsf{N}(D|0,1)
\quad\text{and}\quad
p(D|B) = \textsf{N}(D|3,1) . 
\end{equation}
Now suppose $D =1$. Which model is more consistent with the observation $D$? I.e., which model has the greater marginal likelihood of the fixed data?

Comment: Now I'm even more confused! What are A and B in this case? different parametrizations? why the different parametrization should influence $p(D)$ which is just a probabilistic statement of the observed data, not the parameters? To make a stupid example, let's imagine that we want to investigate the probability of raining $p(R)$ with two competitive models, using either low pressure $p(Lp|R)$ or low temperature alone $p(Lt|R)$. Even if the numerator of the two models change: $p(R|Lp) \times p(Lp)$ vs $p(R|Lt) \times p(Lt)$ the numerator stays p(R) which is just the frequency of rain isn't it?

Comment: That is, why $p(D|A)$ and $p(D|B)$ should not be the same? The base probability of rain doesn't change.

Comment: @Bakaburg I should have referred to the two distributions as models. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you. these days I made some small experiments with R and of course it turned out that the marginal probabilities of data from two different models (i.e. different data/ parameters joint probabilities) are different. So that solves my question. The problem is that I don't get why. Why a statement about the data (which, by Bayesian theory, is fixed) should change based on parameters, since it's unconditional on them? writing it as $p(D|Model)$ doesn't change the problem since the model is defined by its parameterization, isn't it?

Comment: So if the probability of the data is conditional on the model, and the model is defined by the parametrization, -> the probability of the data depends on the parametrization, i.e. $p(D|\theta)$ that is is a conditional likelihood, not a marginal probability. I'm even more confused.

Comment: @Bakaburg I've added a bit more to my answer. See what you think.

Comment: many thanks for your patience with me @mef! When you wrote "marginal likelihood" that triggered something in me (I never considered p(D) as a likelihood) and I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_likelihood on wikipedia. So you want to tell me that even if written $p(D)$ in reality it should be $p(D|M)$ where $M$ is the model functional form, not the parameters' value? That is, the "evidence" probability is conditional on the on how $D = f(\theta)$ is defined, but not on the $\theta$ value?